# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "b_name_key" after save @ManyToOne entity by Spring-boot, Spring-data, Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Duplicate key value violates unique constraint after saving @ManyToOne entity

I tried to save an entity A which has another entity B with a unique field name by spring-data. If B already exists in DB, then an exception "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "b_name_key" will be thrown. Detail: Key (b_name)=(someName) already exists.

```
create table b
(
  b_id         serial primary key,
  b_name varchar(3) not null unique
);

create table a
(
  a_id            serial primary key,
  b_id      int references b (b_id) not null,
);


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long b_id;
    @Column(name = "b_name", unique = true)
    private String bName;

    public B(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public B() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "...";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        B b = (B) o;
        return Objects.equals(bName, b.bName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bName);
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class a implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long a_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;


    public a() {
    }

    public a(B b  ) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        a a = (a) o;
        return Objects.equals(b, a.b)
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(b);
    }
}


@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<Metastasis, Long> {}

@Controller
public class AController {

    private final ARepository aRepository;

    public AController(ARepository aRepository) {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String showaddUserForm() {
        B b = new B("SomeName");
        A a = new A(b);
        aRepository.save(a);
        return "index";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "...repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = "....entities")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I get org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "b_name_key"
  Detail: Key (b_name)=(SomeName) already exists.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Since `a` entity is new, the **PERSIST** operation will be cascaded to the `b` entity which is also new, and fails because there is a record with that key already in the database.

Try something like:

```
// find for B
B b = bRepository.findById(..);
// if not found, create one
if (b == null) {
   b = new B("SomeName");
} 
A a = new A(b);
aRepository.save(a);
```

Comment: Why can't hibernate handle it himself?